# Conditional code for each build phase

Tags: c++, xcode, c-preprocessor

I'm building a project from commandline with:

```
xcodebuild -project ABC.xcodeproj -xcconfig ABC.xcconfig -target "All" -configuration Release
```

**How to have a few lines of codes that differ from one build phase to another?**

e.g. is it possible to have something like this in `ABC.cpp`:

```
#if TARGET == VST2
    MyFunction();      // this will be compiled if and only if we are in VST2 build phase
#endif
```

If so, how and where to define `TARGET` and `VST2`? In the code itself (in which file?) or in the XCode GUI? (in which menu?)

---

This is how the project looks like, and you can see the "build phases" of target "All":

[image]

Comment: I guess that depends on what changes between build targets

Comment: it's only one or two lines like `myfunction();` @UKMonkey

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to select the relevant target in XCode, go in *Build Settings*, and then search for *Preprocessor macros*, and then add a name, like `VST2` for each Debug, Release, Tracer.

Then in the code, it's possible to do:

```
#ifdef VST2
...
#endif
```